# How to change a single material on an object with multiple materials in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, angular-material, unity3d-editor

Please Help

#Problem

I have a 3d model having more then 1 material and i want to change material Element no 2 through c#
Look Image "Material Element Order"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSJwh.jpg)

This is not working

```
  // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject Cube;

    public Material Red;
    public Material Yellow;
    public Material ResultGreen;

    void Start()
    {
        Cube.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1] = ResultGreen;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Renderer.materials`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) is a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) that either returns or assigns an array.

You *can't* change one element of it directly / it makes no sence since what would happen is that you only exchange the element in the array **returned** by the property and then throw away that array. This would change nothing actually.

Or how Unity phrases it and actually tells you exactly what to do

> Note that like all arrays returned by Unity, this returns a **copy** of materials array. If you want to change some materials in it, **get the value, change an entry and set materials back**.

You rather have to do it like

```
// directly store the reference type you need most
public Renderer Cube;

private void Start()
{
    // get the current array of materials
    var materials = Cube.materials;
    // exchange one material
    materials[1] = ResultGreen; 
    // reassign the materials to the renderer
    Cube.materials = materials;
}
```

Comment: just one more question :) is this good idea to change player weapon textures etc using PlayerPrefs ..?

Comment: @Mehmood depends a lot on the context ... if you have a lot of keys etc it might be better to use a proper format like JSON / XML to save and load the settings